# Show a set is open and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, continuity

Let $ U⊂\mathbb R^n$ be an open set,
let $K \subset U$ be a compact set,and let $f:U→\mathbb R$ be a function of class C1.

For $0 < \delta < \operatorname{dist}(K,∂U)$ consider the set $V :=\{x \in U : \operatorname{dist}(x,K)< \delta\}$.

Prove that $ V $ is open, bounded and $K \subset V⊂\overline V ⊂U$.

I assume the set is not closed so it is open and it is bounded since K is a bounded set so it has a max and dist(K,∂U) is also bounded. How would I show these results more rigorously?

Comment: If a set is not closed it need not be open. You need to take  a fresh  look at the definitions.

Comment: sorry i meant the complement of the set is closed if thats right

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in what you wrote!

*I assume the set is not closed so it is open.* A set can be neither open nor closed. So not being closed is not a reason to be open! $[0,1) \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $\mathbb R$ endowed with the usual topology is an example.

A proof can be based on the fact that the map $\varphi: x \mapsto d(x, K)$ is continuous on $U$. Therefore the inverse image of the open subset $(-\infty, \delta) \subseteq \mathbb R$ under $\varphi$ is open. This inverse image is exactly $V$.

$V$ is bounded because $K$ is bounded being compact. Suppose that $R_K$ is such that $d(0,x) \le R_K$ for all $x \in K$. Then for $v \in V$ you have $d(0,v) \le R_K + \delta$.

The requested inclusions are immediate.